# how to sum first 5 values in column B corresponding to a particular text in column C?

Tags: excel, numbers, sum

I want to add first "n" number of values of one column say B when the corresponding values of another column say C in same row equals to certain "text"

Comment: Did you try `Data > Subtotal` feature in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it as non-array formula I suggest something like this in D1:

```
=IF((C1="text")*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,"text")=5),SUMIF(C$1:C1,"text",B$1:B1),"")
```

And copy down.

A different approach would be using an array formula like:

```
{=SUMIF(C1:INDEX(C1:C100,SMALL(IF(C1:C100="text",ROW(C1:C100)),5)),"text",B:B)}
```

Which will do the whole work in one step ;)

Answer (score 2):

With data in **B1** through **C20**

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(C1="text",1,"")
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(C2="text",COUNT($D$1:D1)<5),1,"")
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D:D,B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: You also could change the first formula from `=IF(C1="text",1,"")` to `=IF(C1="text",B1,"")` and the second formula to from `=IF(AND(C2="text",COUNT($D$1:D1)<5),1,"")` to `=IF(AND(C2="text",COUNT($D$1:D1)<5),B2,"")`. This way the third formula would just be `=SUM(D:D)` and the `=SUMPRODUCT(D:D,B:B)`-array could be avoided... or just change the third formula to `=SUMIF(D:D,1,B:B)` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel  Both are good alternatives.................I especially like the *SUMIF()* approach!

Answer (score 1):

For single array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW($C$1:$C$20)<=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$1:$C$20)/($C$1:$C$20="text"),5))*($C$1:$C$20="text")*$B$1:$B$20)
```

[image]